# During applications, how can I prove I was the first author of the papers that I couldn't become first author for various reasons?

Tags: publications, authorship, research-undergraduate

One year ago, I started working on a subject with one of the professors of our department. The idea was mine, and all of the subsequent steps including modellings, simulations, generation of figures, writing the paper and even responding to the reviewers were done by myself completely, and the professor just reviewed the paper and reminded some typos and minor mistakes of this kind, and also added a short paragraph (completely unnecessary in my opinion) to the Introduction section.

But at the end he wrote his name as the first author and submitted the paper. He told me that being second author for him means getting no credit from the department.

Anyway, I'm going to apply for grad school, and he told me he will *compensate* in the recommendation he will write for me.

As this is my only published paper as an undergrad, and being first author means everything for me in my application, is there any way for me to prove to the admission committees (or the professors; whoever will review my application) that I was the main contributor of the paper?

Comment: Don't underestimate the importance of the letters of recommendation when you apply to graduate school. They are just as important as your vita - and for things like research, they are perhaps more important. You will also describe your own work in your research statement. In comparison to those things, the author ordering on a publication is not going to be very significant.

Comment: Even being "first author" is not always significant.  My name is first on a couple of papers to which I contributed very little because the authors' names are listed in alphabetical order.

Comment: I am under the impression that, unless a paper is of unique author, it would not get the committees attention. And I am personally adopting this principle in my applications to doctoral programs.

Comment: @Kurt That depends entirely on the field. In my field, theoretical computer science, one-author papers are not uncommon but two to four authors (almost always ordered alphabetically) is very much the norm. You certainly wouldn't hold it against somebody that they had "only" worked in collaboration with others.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yep, thanks. Indeed, I just want to share the OP with what I know, without any intention to arbitrarily generalize my opinion to a universal one. The decision right, of course, belongs and only belongs to the OP :)

Comment: @Kurt Of course, yes. When commenting and answering, it's good to bear in mind that many things differ substantially between different fields and be careful to state whether you're talking your own field (and state what that is!) or academia in general.

Comment: @Kurt Honestly speaking, I doubt whether your statement is true in any field, and I am curious what field you have in mind. Single-author papers by undergrads are very uncommon, unless they appear at undergraduate research venues (and then they are usually not full papers). So I'd think a paper authored by an undergraduate and a professor (no graduate student collaborator), that appears as a regular scholarly publication in a reputable journal or conference, would get any committee's attention.

Comment: His goodwill is worth more to you than a first author paper, at this stage in your career.

Comment: "He told me that being second author for him means getting no credit from the department." I am stunned to see how common this kind of argument is! Authorship and order of authors are not decided according to needs or benefits of the people involved, but according to their contribution and merit. Unfortunately, your best move right now is plausibly to let it be, and move on (while putting that professor in your personal black-list for the future).

Comment: Let's not forget that what the professor did was unprofessional and (imho) unethical. Think twice (or thrice) about if you want to work with them in the future.

Comment: Not that this really matters, but the title doesn't _quite_ reflect the actual question. I came in half-expecting to answer "the only way you can prove you are the first author is to look at the list of names on the paper and see whether yours appears first :-P"

Comment: Without the professors input would you have got it published, e.g. would you have know how to get it published?

Comment: @Ian Yes, of course. Actually, the professor requested me to prepare the paper in a format that was obsolete according the the guide for authors (in the journals website), and I wrote the paper in the new, preferred format.

Comment: @Mostafa To be fair - whether the prof. was up-to-date in terms of which formatting they currently expect is hardly the important question.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Re "Authorship and order of authors are not decided according to needs or benefits of the people involved, but according to their contribution and merit." Although [an earlier comment](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32013/during-applications-how-can-i-prove-i-was-the-first-author-of-the-papers-that-i#comment71336_32013) mentions a field where authors are usually listed alphabetically.  Of course, if that's the case here, then the department would be quite unfair to only credit first authors.  (Why does Aho get so many more departmental awards than Zadeh?)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: my field is one of these, where author are listed alphabetically. It means that all authors of a publication are co-first authors, with equal merit assumed. In evaluation, the order of the authors is never considered, so the only issue in this case is authorship, not the order.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner OP said "[the professor] wrote his name as the first author ... . He told me that being second author for him means getting no credit from the department."  In an alphabetically-ordered field, no primary author in that department would want to work with any "alphabetic inferior".  My comment was more to point out the ill-informed nature of such departmental policies, not the practice of the venue.  Such a department would tend to recognize Aho much more frequently than Zadeh, since Zadeh would so rarely be a first author (or first-listed among first coauthors).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: this is no place for such an extended discussion, but departmental policies taking author rank into account hopefully only happen in fields where author rank is relevant, and not alphabetical.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Of course.  I was just pointing out that in addition to the probably unethical behavior here, the department's policy is sort of strange, too.

Comment: Don't forget that in many institutions the 'boss' of a department gets first authorship (or last authorship depending on the institution) of all papers by default. That can be a fairly common thing, and if you write a note explaining all the work you actually did (but don't be defensive or bitter about the authorship order) that would be fine for an undergrad.

Comment: Unfortunately, your boss's behavior is rater unethical. If you want fix this you should do it in your school, most probably you have mixed chances to come out without injuries. I would strongly advise again bringing up this issue in a interview to another school if you didn't prove your right in your own department. That would sound really bad, and just make your position worse. Note, i do not say that what your prof did was right or anything like that - but focus on what doesn't hurt your career.

Answer (score 31):

> As this is my only published paper as an undergrad, and being first author means everything for me in my application, is there anyway for me to prove to the admission committees (or the professors; whoever will review my application) that I was the main contributor of the paper?

Short answer: no. Aside from the professor writing in his letter that he did indeed not do the work and just put his name front to brush up his CV, I see no way how you can *prove* that you were indeed the "actual" first author. And, given that this would essentially mean that the professor confesses unethical behavior, I see very little chance of this happening.

Anyway, I am not so sure whether being first author means "everything" for you. Undergrads are often not the first authors of publications (for many reasons, not just the unethical reason that you were denied first authorship). Further, if I see a paper with a senior author and an undergrad, I am not assuming that the professor did most of the hard work and undergrad just advised - independently of how the authors are ordered. I would assume your average admission committee to be similarly realistic.

Comment: This. It's implied; most will assume you did most of the work and know that having the professor as first author is really a (bad) formality at some places. I also agree that being first author doesn't mean everything; even being a co-author on a paper as an undergrad is a feat that fewer-than-average students accomplish!

Answer (score 3):

Your question breaks down into distinct subquestions and assumptions, we need to call out each of them separately, especially because you have the importance wrong:

1. **How important is being first named author** [as long as you're second, obviously], in your field. You claimed *"being first author means everything for me in my application"*
2. **Is fighting this fight worth it?** Is it strategically worth picking this one or letting it go? 2b) Also: is it important going forward to preserve your relationship with professor (especially if it sounds like you'll stay in the same dept?)
3. **How do you actually prove you originated the work/ideas?** (This is pretty self-evident and is the least important question)

Answers from experience (almost all of us know people who've been in this situation):

1. **You seem to be making a huge wrong assumption** here, seems like you extrapolated the application's artificial format **to believe in general you will not get any credit unless you're first-named**. Generally everyone knows the deal with academia and tenure-track, it's an imperfect little world, people will understand he is under pressure from his own tenure-track metrics. Yes it's somewhat bad ethics, but this is utterly different to omitting your name entirely, stealing your idea for a startup or patent, esp. when rejecting the associated thesis, stealing your funding and redirecting it to other purposes etc. Outside in the real world noone gives a ****  if you were first named author; at interviews or in applications you will be given adequate chance to demonstrate whether you were/were not the prime mover; in fact people may respect the team-member vibe if you diplomatically say "we" and "our idea" while making it blatantly obvious you did the work and wrote the professor's promotion ticket.
2. **To quote Def Leppard's fine song, "Let It Go..."**
   You have to answer this question: on a scale of 1-10, how was prof's behavior overall, and factor in "he told me he will compensate in my recommendation". Sounds like an 8/10 to me. Believe me, there are scumbags out there, and it ain't him.
3. Pretty self-evident, and irrelevant. Notebooks, notes, SCM checkins, emails, drafts. If in future you get a really clever idea [while in academia], send a dated email to yourself (/burn a CD and certified-mail it yourself, unopened). Read also about the concept *[Reduction to practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_to_practice)* in US patent law, for the future when you're working for a company.

Answer (score -3):

If you kept a stack of drafts, produce them. While not definite proof, it would be very hard to overcome even if the professor were to try. Likely, he won't and you win by default.

Comment: Seems like a perfect way to start one's career.

Comment: Even if this is probably a fight you can't (or don't want to) win -- \*sigh\* -- note that versioning repository timestamps or similar *may* work as proof, as long as you don't control the server (and hence the timestamps/commit messages are believable).